# .PY files opening with windows commend prompt

Tags: python, windows

My .py files are opening with windows command prompt. 
How do I set another software as default?

I've tired to set Pycharm as the default program for .PY files but the check box is greyed out. Pycharm opens the file but never becomes default.

This problem started happening when I was first tired to install the Google Data Library earlier today.

https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/python_client_lib#installing-the-google-data-library

Running "run_data_tests.py" would give me errors on Pycharm

```
Microsfot Wiondows [version 56.1.7601]
copy right (c) 2009 microsoft coporation. All rights reserved.
```

So silly me decided to open "run_data_tests.py" with the windows command prompt. 
Thinking some how it would fix everything. BTW the check box was still clickable at this point. I ran the code and and it did nothing so I went back to change the .PY settings to open with Pycharm again but the box was grayed out.

More Information:

Python 3.5.2
Windows 7

Python location

```
cd Users\WIN 7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe
```

Any information would be helpful I have spent a couple hours trying to figure it out.

Comment: Sounds like your Windows Registry got modified. Not sure if doing this is a good idea, but check out this question & answer's suggestion (and others similar to it) [How to enable the “Always use the selected program to open this kind of file” checkbox](http://superuser.com/q/835526)

Comment: The default is for scripts to be executable when double-clicked or run directly in a command line. In that case, they should open with py.exe using the default `Python.File` file type (ProgId). Assuming you can get the right-click context menu "open with" to work, such as by manually deleting the .py user selection in Explorer's registry settings, then in the "open with" dialog the launcher should be the "Python" entry with a rocket in the upper left-hand corner. For 3.6 this icon will be changed to resemble the Win+R dialog's icon.

Comment: Thank you guys so much the replies helped me solve the issue